# nhibernate transaction management in asp.net WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, transactions, webforms

I've been doing some research on transaction management for NHibernate for ASP.Net applications (Webforms).   Most articles I found tend to favour the transaction-per-request approach.  While I understand the session-per-request, and am totally in favour of it.  However, I don't exactly understand the reasoning behind the transaction-per-request.

My applications use version-field to do concurrency checks.  If a problem, such a StaleObjectException, or anything else is thrown, this is thrown once you call `Transaction.Commit()`.  My issue is that if this is in the end of request, you cannot easily know which method actually had the problematic code, and it is extremely difficult to rollback from the issue.

For example, in a StaleObjectException, normally one needs just to re-run the method, with the updated data.

Any ideas on this, and any practices for transaction management?  I tend to favour opening as much transactions as possible, based on the business logic.  The issue with multiple transactions is where to actually begin/end the transaction.

Answer (score 2):

The transaction-per-request paradigm makes sense when you step back and think of the underlying nature of a web application.  It is a request/response system, nothing more.  A user submits a request for "something", which the application translates into performing an action or a series of actions, then the application sends a response to the user to indicate its current updated state.

In this model each request for action to the application can (*should* arguably) be atomic.  After all, from the perspective of the user, conceptually what failed when there was an error?  The request failed.  Upon such a failure, the application should respond in two ways:

1. Roll back any partial changes associated with processing the request so that the persisted data isn't left in a "partial" or "undefined" state.
2. Inform the user (in the response) that the request has failed in some way.

   > My issue is that if this is in the end of request, you cannot easily know which method actually had the problematic code, and it is extremely difficult to rollback from the issue.

Can you show an example with code?  I wonder if the problem might be addressed by other elements of the application's design than the transaction structure.  Perhaps the processing of requests isn't properly atomic or encapsulated.

*(Comments indicate that the below may be more personal opinion and is normal behavior for NHibernate)*

> For example, in a StaleObjectException, normally one needs just to re-run the method, with the updated data.

While I'm certainly no expert on NHibernate, I hesitate to understand what's being said here.  Generally when an exception occurs, simply "trying again" is *very often* not a good way to handle the exception.

Comment: Yes, it is labelled as an 'exception', it is an exception detailing a mismatch due to optimistic concurrency.  When this happens, most of the times you can easily 'fix' the error by re-running the query.  This question on StackOverflow can give you maybe some insight on how NHibernate works regarding optimistic concurrency/version checking (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409146/nhibernate-handling-staleobjectstateexception-to-always-commit-client-changes).  Thus, for such cases it wouldn't make sense to have the error being raised at the `Page_EndRequest` state.

Comment: @KarlCassar: Fair enough, though if anything it only reinforces my distaste with most frameworks.  Any time the response is "Oh, with that framework that happens sometimes.  You just need to remember to do this other non-standard thing and it'll probably be fine" then I feel that the framework has failed in some way.  Not that I expect any code to be perfect, of course.  But if a particular library requires that I engage in otherwise bad practices in order to use it, I probably won't use it.  But that's just personal opinion and outside the scope of the question, really :)

Comment: How exactly is that a bad practice, and how would one overcome such an 'exception' in a better way if you opt to use optimistic concurrency checking?